# Why is the ratio of the $||a-b||_2$ and $||a+b||_2$, $\tan[\angle (a,b)/2]$ when $a$ and $b$ are unit vectors with $a^Tb \geq 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

Let $a$, $b\in\mathbb{R}^n$.
When $a^Tb \geq 0$ and $\|a\|_2=\|b\|_2=1$, can we prove $$\frac{\|a-b\|_2}{\|a+b\|_2} = \tan{\frac{\angle(a,b)}{2}}\text{?}$$

In the 2D case, this is clear from examining the parallelogram spanned by $a$ and $b$; compare [this diagram](http://prnt.sc/pjAoLnWfKMRp) by commenter across.  But I can't visualize vectors in higher dimensions (say, $n=4$), so I'd like an algebraic proof.  Is there one?

Comment: As a start, $a+b$ and $a-b$ are diagonals of the rhombus formed by unit vectors $a, b$. Diagonals bisect the angles in rhombus...

Comment: hint2: diagonals bisect each other at 90 degrees in rhombus

Comment: https://prnt.sc/pjAoLnWfKMRp

Comment: Yes! I can see this from two dimensional setting. But how to expand the conclusion from $R^2$ to $R^n$?

Comment: does it matter how many dimensions ? two vectors still span a plane...

Comment: It is kind of hard for me to imagine what the vectors $a$ and $b$ look like in $\mathbb{R}^n$ when $n \geq 4$. They still span a two dimensional subspace but I can not imagine it directly. Is it possible to show it by some algebra rather than geometry?

Comment: Ohk... you may take horizontal and perpendicular projections of $a+b$ along $a$. Ratio of these gives $\tan \angle (a,b)/2$  il try to post as answer shortly,

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, without referring to angles directly in $\mathbb{R}^n$, use the trig identity:

$$\tan \frac{u}{2} =  \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos u}{1+\cos u}}$$

note $\cos\angle (a,b) = a\cdot b $

$$\tan\frac{\angle (a,b)}{2} = \sqrt{\frac{1-a\cdot b}{1+a\cdot b}} = \frac{\|a-b\|}{\|a+b\|}$$

Answer (score 0):

When $a^Tb\ge 0$ angles are acute, so we can assume $\angle (a+b,a)  = \frac{\angle(a,b)}{2}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

[image]

decompose $a+b$ along $a$ and perpendicular of $a$
say $x$ is the magnitude of component vector parallel to $a$:
$$x=a\cdot(a+b) = 1+a\cdot b $$

say $y$ is the magnitude of component vector perpendicular to $a$:
$$y^2 = (a+b)^2-x^2 = (1+a\cdot b)(1-a\cdot b)$$

---

$$\tan\frac{\angle (a,b)}{2} = \frac{y}{x} =\sqrt{\frac{1-a\cdot b}{1+a\cdot b}} =\frac{\|a-b\|}{\|a+b\|}$$